# Modify the gradient of a shape drawable in code in Android

Tags: java, android, button, colors, gradient

I've been scouring the web and SO but still no luck.

Problem:

App connects to a server to retrieve a few colours that are then assigned to various controls in the app.

My problem is that I'd like to use style defined in xml for Edittext and Button controls, but if i set the background colour of the control it removes any of my predefined styling.

I have a selector drawable with defined styles for pressed, focused and normal

How can I modify the gradient within the selector from code.

Please note: it is a requirement that the colour comes from the server, (which is just a hex value)

main (JAVA)

```
int gradientColour1= "comes from server"
int gradientColour2= "also comes from server"

Button btnNext = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnnext);
btnNext.setBackgroundColor(gradientColor1);
```

is there a way I can do something like this: (pseudo)

```
Gradient grad = new Gradient(gradientColor1,gradientColor2,90);
btnNext.setBackgroundGradient(grad);
btnNext.setBorderRadius(15);
```

I need to be able to get the colours via a webrequest, not predefined in xml

There must be a way that I can do this.
If I have to do away with the pre-defined styles then that's fine.

I'm pretty new to android/java and Stack Overflow so please be gentle
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
public void setGradientColor(int endColor, int startColor) {
    GradientDrawable gradient = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP, new int[]  {endColor, startColor});
    gradient.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
    gradient.setCornerRadius(10.f);
    btnNext.setBackgroundDrawable(gradient);
}
```